# Format String to Currency in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is it possbile to convert a string via LINQ to a currency within the following code: (I would like to get the following Format :1.234,56

```
} into g        
   select new        
   {
       Kunde_Kz = g.Key.Kunde_Kz,
       Geschäftspartner = g.Key.Geschäftspartner,
       Art_Gruppe = g.Key.Art_Gruppe,
       //Auftragsposition = g.Key.Auftragsposition,
       Deckungsbeitrag = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Deckungsbeitrag")),
       Erlös = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Erlös")),
       Dienst = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Dienst")),
       IS_Erlös = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("IS_Erlös")),
       Ware_in = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Ware_in")),
       Ware_out = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Ware_out")),
       Mieten = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Mieten")),
       Kosten = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Kosten")),
       Dienst_kosten = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Dienst_kosten")),
       Verarbeitung = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Verarbeitung")),
       Ware_in_kosten = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Ware_in_kosten")),
       Ware_out_kosten = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Ware_out_kosten")),
       Mieten_kosten = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Mieten_kosten"))

   }).ToList();
```

Comment: A double or decimal has no format. If your code works you dont have strings. If it doesn't work you have to tell us the error message.

Comment: It will only get a format when you output it to a string, in which case specify the format there.

Answer (score 2):

'N' ToString format: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString)

Summary:
The numeric ("N") format specifier converts a number to a string of the form "-d,ddd,ddd.ddd…", where "-" indicates a negative number symbol if required, "d" indicates a digit (0-9), "," indicates a group separator, and "." indicates a decimal point symbol. The precision specifier indicates the desired number of digits after the decimal point. If the precision specifier is omitted, the number of decimal places is defined by the current NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits property.

```
123456d.ToString("N2") // outputs "123.456,00" or "123,456.00" depending on culture
```

Comment: ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")) for the german culture which it seems he is using

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
Mieten_kosten = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Mieten_kosten")).ToString("c")
```

Then the `Mieten_kosten` variable will contain a string that has a currency symbol. Assuming that the machine has a German locale setting the `Mieten_kosten` would formatted as you write currency and be suffixed by a euro sign (€).

A detailed example:

```
var cult = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"); // make sure we get the german locale
(12222.3).ToString("c", cult).Dump(); // outputs 12.222,30 €
```